# .NET questions with a language tag that is irrelevant

Tags: discussion, tags

Should questions on Stack Overflow that are about the .NET Framework which have no relevance to a particular language include a language tag? (Should the language tag be removed?)

This [question about the stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137863/stacktrace-information-in-net-release-mode-build) is tagged c# but really could apply to VB.NET or any other .NET language. Or does it just not matter?

Comment: probably you got the wrong example but I think the question is good. Here are other examples, there are plenty of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142382/mimic-emulate-a-specific-screen-resolution-for-sizing-winforms
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142126/how-would-you-format-datetime-in-international-format
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141644/wpf-cannot-get-custom-attached-property-to-work-as-a-trigger-property

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that this depends on the question itself. If a question is tagged with `C#`, `VB.NET` or `F#` then I assume that the questioner is fluent with that language and is looking for a 'coded solution' in that language.

In the case of your example question, the `C#` tag is irrelevant and should be removed, since the question applies to MSBuild and the .NET Framework itself.

Comment: I agree in principle, but C# and .NET are *effectively* synonymous, just like "ain't" is a word despite the protestations of my first grade teacher.

Comment: @Randolpho: Yes and No. People might use it as a synonym...but that is in my eyes bad practice. It's like calling an angle-grinder Flex, or any PC Windows. It might be daily use, but it's still not quiet right or accurate.

Comment: As I wrote, I *agree*, in principle. I, too, feel there's a very distinct... distinction between the languages of .NET and the .NET framework itself. But to the vast majority of folks out there, the two are synonymous -- just like Java and the JVM. And, just like "ain't", you're going to have a very hard time suppressing it. It's better to just accept it and move on. :)

Answer (score 5):

The tag isn't just for categorization of the question, it's also to help others find the question through the RSS feed and the like.

Tagging it C# ensures that a large cross-section of people that use the .NET Framework daily will see your question. They may not be following the `.NET` tag (partially because it applies to every C# and every VB.NET question out there), but they will follow the `C#` tag, which means more eyeballs for your problems, and more chances of an answer.

It's not accurate to do that, but it's useful. In time, I would expect it to be edited out, but in that golden time before you have an answer, it's nice to get as many eyeballs on it as possible.

Comment: I'm going to start tagging PostgreSQL questions as `[C#]` to get more eyeballs!

Comment: @perbert - that won't help you, because C# people are unlikely to know much about PostGreSql.  You need to tag for your audience.

Comment: @Joel: you seem to mistake me for someone who talks seriously.

Comment: +1. My main language at work is VB (for historical reasons), but I've noticed a much higher response rate when translating the code examples in my questions to C#, just for the sake of being able to give them the `C#` tag. I don't really like it, because the sample language is almost always irrelevant to the (.NET Framework) question, but it just works so well...

Comment: @Heinzi, I have found that a quesions with code in C# is more lickly to have been writen by someone with at least a bit of understanding then a question with code in VB.NET, hence I tend to advoid quesions with code in VB.NET

Answer (score 3):

Is it not that many (I know I do) puts VB.NET or C# because we want or **prefer** the *answer* in that language?

If the tag is C#, I answer with examples in C#, if the tag is VB.Net I answer with examples in VB.Net. If there is only a .Net tag and no more clues I let the context or my preferred language be the choise of language

Comment: Exactly. But his example does not ask for anything coded, but for the behavior of MSBuild and the Framework itself.

Comment: @Bobby the question askers don't always know if code will be required. So the fact that it didn't require code doesn't matter, because if it did, the OP wants C# and therefore tagged it as such.

Comment: @devinb: But in this case it's obviously not necessary...shouldn't questions 'evolve' over time, including changing of tags if they become obsolete?

Comment: @Bobby, If the *question* changes, the tags should change. However, that question is vague and *could* be code related. We don't know that he is talking about visual studio debugging, he could just as easily be talking about reflection, which *would* require source code. And a language tag.

Comment: @devinb: Yes. But he was not looking for a code related solution. He asked a general question about the build-process and the answer is a general answer about the framework (and is accepted). Which means that the question and the answer seems to have nothing to do with C# at all, rendering the tag...arrr...what's the word? Inaccurate? Misplaced?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would be too difficult force or explain people to use `.net` tag instead of `C#` and `VB.NET` tags for question not language specific.

In my opinion if you see a question that could be considered *".NET language irrelevant"* and that contains only the tag `VB.NET` or `C#`, just edit it and add the tag `.net`, or `.net-n.n` if the version of framework is relevant.

**EDIT**: **some numbers**

now 29/06/10 17:50 (+1 timezone) on SO:

- .net [45'242]
- c# [90'372]
- vb.net [9'293]

it seems that `c#` is used double times of `.net` and I don't think that we have 45K C# questions on the language self.

Maybe it could be an idea to add tag `.net` to `vb.net` and `c#` questions where is not still there directly with a server script? What do you think?

Comment: Some of the questions with [c#] but not [.net] have 5 tags already. Global tag addition will invoke chaos as a result. Either we end up with questions with 6 tags, or we end up clearing those questions of perhaps useful tags. Later case is even worse because global rewrites *change history*, so there wouldn't even be a trace of the original tags in some places.