# Implied tags (presence of tag A implies presence of tag B)

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Hi,

we already have tag synonyms, what about having also "single-directional synonyms"?

For example: We have tags like C# or WPF. Both of these subjects are inevitably related to .net and should be tagged as such. But many people don't respect this and often tag C# related question only with C#, or WPF related questions only with WPF.

It would be nice if for example **30k+ users could define an "implied tag"**, which would e.g. mean that the .net tag is added automatically when someone tags a question as C#.

**Why would this be helpful?** I would for example like to have all the .net related questions pop up in my Google Reader (RSS). If I added all the .net related tags, I would receive many questions two (or more) times. (I don't want them via email, I like the Google Reader interface much more suitable for this). But if I subscribed to .net only, I would miss many interesting questions.

**EDIT:**

If you don't like my example with .net, there are more:

- XAML => WPF
- .NET-4.0, .NET-3.5 => .NET
- J2EE => Java
- STL => C++

Also, this would be only a tool to reduce the retagging load, as are tag synonyms.

Comment: This could work well for the RPG and IT Security communities also, I think.  There are several tags which are automatically relevant to another in one direction, and it would help to reduce tag clutter on the questions if these relationships could be made.

Comment: More examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info) eg Oracle11g => Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Any user with at least 500 rep can already retag questions (without approval required). If you think that one is missing from a question that you're reading, add it yourself!

Users with at least 10k rep get an inline tag-editing interface, which streamlines the process even more.

An automated solution isn't necessarily the best choice here. Consider that the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) tag doesn't *always* belong on questions that are about C# or WPF. A purist would argue that the .NET tag *only* applies to questions specifically about the .NET Framework itself (think the BCL or CLR). I imagine I'm not always consistent with this viewpoint in my own edits, but I certainly try to keep it in mind. An automated policy that adds the .NET tag to any question remotely related to the .NET ecosystem would render that tag even more useless than it already is.

To play devil's advocate, should we also tag questions about [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) with [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio)? The user is very likely to be using Visual Studio to write the code. What about [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf)? Surely all of those questions could be accurately tagged [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) or [expression-blend](/questions/tagged/expression-blend), because there aren't many other development environments available for WPF. But the amount of clutter that would add to *each* question is nearly inconceivable, not to mention that it would fill up the allowed 5 tag maximum, preventing users from adding other important *distinguishing* tags.

You may also find these related discussions interesting:

- [.NET questions with a language tag that is irrelevant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55302/net-questions-with-a-language-tag-that-is-irrelevant)
- [Standards for retagging due to language specificity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73917/standards-for-retagging-due-to-language-specificity)

Comment: The Visual Studio example is not relevant, if only because we have SharpDevelop :) I also added a couple more examples to the OP.

Comment: @mzabsky: Yeah, I considered that. That's why I said *very likely*. I would venture a guess that the overwhelming majority of .NET developers are working in Visual Studio, especially since there's a free Express version. Not all, but the point was that it's at least as likely as *all* C# questions are to apply to the .NET Framework. The "implied" tags for WPF are an even better example.